$\begin{cases}x_1^5 + 7x_1e^{y_1}=x_2^5 + 7x_2e^{y_2}\\y_1 - x_1^4 = y_2 - x_2^4\end{cases}.$ Show that $x_1 = x_2$ and $y_1 = y_2.$
$\begin{cases}x_1^5 + 7x_1e^{y_1}=x_2^5 + 7x_2e^{y_2}\\y_1 - x_1^4 = y_2 - x_2^4\end{cases}$ for $x_1,x_2, y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.
I need to show that $x_1 = x_2$ and $y_1 = y_2$. It's clear that if $x_1 = 0$, then $x_2 = 0$ and $y_1 = y_2$. Similarly, if $x_2 = 0$, then $x_1 = 0$ and $y_1 = y_2$. It remains to prove for the case when $x_1, x_2 \neq 0$. However, I couldn't seem to find a good substitution or some working maneuver to simplify the system of equations. I hope to receive some hints. Thank you very much!

@lulu Hi, they are real numbers. I'm editing the question now.

The function $f(x,y)=x^5+7xe^y$ is onto from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$. Taking an arbitrary real $a$, the curve $f(x,y)=a$ has many points. However for the system
$$\begin{cases}x^5+7xe^y=a\\x^4-y=b\end{cases}$$ the resultant in $x$ is
$$g(x)=x^5+7xe^{x^4-b}-a=0\hspace 1cm (1)$$ Taking derivative in $(1)$ we have
$$g'(x)=5x^4+(28x^4+7)e^{x^4-b}$$ which is always positive (its minimum is equal to $7e^{-b}$).
Thus the system correspond to an unique real point $(x,y)$ which proves the asked equality of points $(x_1,y_1)=(x_2,y_2)$.

The challenge is to prove that
$$\forall x_1,x_2,y_1\in\Bbb R\quad x_1^5 + 7x_1e^{y_1}=x_2^5 + 7x_2e^{y_1-x_1^4+x_2^4}\implies x_1=x_2,$$
i.e.
$$\forall x_1,x_2\in\Bbb R,\forall c>0\quad x_1^5-x_2^5=c(x_2e^{x_2^4}-x_1e^{x_1^4})\implies x_1=x_2.$$
This is due to the fact that $t\mapsto te^{t^4}$ is strictly increasing on $\Bbb R$.

From the first equation, we have
$$x_1 (x_1^4 + 7\mathrm{e}^{y_1})
= x_2 (x_2^4 + 7\mathrm{e}^{y_2}), \tag{1}$$
which results in
$$x_1^4 (x_1^4 + 7\mathrm{e}^{y_1})^4
= x_2^4 (x_2^4 + 7\mathrm{e}^{y_2})^4. \tag{2}$$
From the second equation, we have
$$y_1 - y_2 = x_1^4 - x_2^4. \tag{3}$$
We claim that $x_1^4 = x_2^4$.
If $x_1^4 > x_2^4$, from (3), we have
$y_1 > y_2$, and then $x_1^4 (x_1^4 + 7\mathrm{e}^{y_1})^4
> x_2^4 (x_2^4 + 7\mathrm{e}^{y_2})^4$
which contradicts (2).
If $x_1^4 < x_2^4$, from (3), we have
$y_1 < y_2$, and then $x_1^4 (x_1^4 + 7\mathrm{e}^{y_1})^4
< x_2^4 (x_2^4 + 7\mathrm{e}^{y_2})^4$
which contradicts (2).
The claim is proved.
From (3), we have $y_1 = y_2$. From (1), we have $x_1 = x_2$.
We are done.
